# Android - Daily notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, alarmmanager

I have this app which launches the function `notifiy()`in the NotificationService when ever device is started or when app is opened
my question is how I can make this notifiy() function be made on specific times daily for example at (12:00 AM, 3:00 AM) I searched for a while and all I saw is working with AlarmManager but I don't understand how to use it in my code

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));
```

**BootReceiver**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context,NotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

**NotificationService**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Nullable
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            notifiy();
        }
        @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent("com.company.app");
        intent.putExtra("yourvalue","torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    public void notifiy(){
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("RSSPullService");
        Intent mIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(""));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,mIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        Notification.Builder builder;
        builder=new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText("")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images);
        Notification notification=builder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.msound);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If you want to set `alarm` after `launching` app then you can add below codes in your `MainActivity's` `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Schedule Date & time
    Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();
    target.set(2017, 5, 3, 12, 0, 0); 

    // Intent
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    mIntent.putExtra("MSG_ID", "SOME MESSAGE");

    // Pending broadcast intent
    PendingIntent mPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Set alarm
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, target.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mPI);       

}
```

**2.** If you want to set `alarm` after `boot` completion, then you can add that code in `BootReceiver's` `onReceive()` method:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Schedule Date & time
        Calendar target = Calendar.getInstance();
        target.set(2017, 5, 3, 12, 0, 0); 

        // Intent
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("MSG_ID", "SOME MESSAGE");

        // Pending broadcast intent
        PendingIntent mPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Alarm manager
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Set alarm
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, target.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mPI);   

    }

}
```

**Here is `AlarmReceiver` class:**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;


public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Called ");
    }
}
```

**Declare `AlarmReceiver` class in `AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
<receiver
     android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE.AlarmReceiver">

</receiver>
```

Comment: When alarm trigger AlarmReceiver's onReceive() method will be invoked

Comment: AlarmReveiver is same as smy BootReceiver class?

Comment: also where notifiy() is called?

Comment: You have already called this notifiy() from NotificationService  class

Comment: here is the process: Set alarm > Alarm trigger > AlarmReceiver onReceive() called > Start NotificationService >> call notify() ............Thats it

Comment: that code in the mainactivity oncreate won't be run when the app is not launched ? sorry I'm a little bit confused

Comment: 1. If you want to set alarm after launching app then you can add that code in onCreate(). 2. If you want to set alarm after boot  then you can add that code in BootReceiver's onReceive() method and remove context.startService(new Intent(context,NotificationService.class)).